# Wrap a property accessor in between span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hook, string-concatenation

I am trying to wrap a concatenated string in  that includes an property accessor.  Is that possible?  Ultimately, I am trying to make every other line the same color.

I have tried multiple ways of wrapping the span in "" without including the property accessor so it doesn't become text.  Ex. `"<span>" + val.joke + "</span>"` but it doesn't work.

```
$(".knock").addClass("knock").html("<span> Knock Knock! </span>" + "<br>").show("fade", "fast").delay(2000).show(function() {

  $(".knock").append("Who's there?" + "<br>", html).show("fade", "slow").delay(2000).show(function() {

    $(".knock").append(val.joke + "<br>", html).show("fade", "fast").delay(2000).show(function() {

      $(".knock").append(val.joke + " who?" + "<br>", html).show("fade", "fast").delay(3000).show(function() {

        $(".knock").append("— " + val.punchline, html).show("fade", "fast");
```

Using it with: `$("span").css("color", "white");`

The first line works great, but the third line within the `.append` area is the one I can't get to work:

```
$(".knock").append(val.joke + "<br>", html).show("fade", "fast").delay(2000).show(function() {
```

UPDATE: I honestly don't know where to begin to pull a snippet that would register anything, so I am posting a link to the project:
https://codepen.io/keepcoding/pen/dZprbj

The first line above starts on the JavaScript page on line 47.  It is pulling from JSON files.  There are "what do you get?" jokes and "knock knock" jokes.
Both types have a joke and a punchline.

"Val" represents the id of the joke chosen. And if I put "" around the val.joke or val.punchline like .html(" val.joke " + "
", html), it displays the word "val.joke" instead of pulling and displaying the joke.  I hope this is what you were looking for and thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "*so it doesn't become text*"? What does the `val.joke` (accessor) property return? Please [edit] your question to include the code that defines `val`.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? Just put the code in a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/1541563), and define `val` so that the code runs to show the problem you're describing.

Comment: confirm value of `val.joke` with `console.log(val.joke)` or `console.log(val)`